# In Anylogic, how to Randomly Select from a list of items

Tags: random, selection, anylogic

In Anylogic what is the easiest way to select randomly from a group of items you choose. For example, If you are creating new Customer agents and you have three existing populations of customers: customers1, customers2, customers3. How do you do a type of randomFrom(customers1, customers2, customers3) to choose a population to put the new agents in? Do you first put the customers1...3 in a collection (three in all) or a list? OR how would you just merely choose randomly from a few items? I know there is the randomlyCreate function that allows you to randomly create agents of different types for a list,  but i cant find a function that will randomly choose something from a list i create either of the same type of object or a completely random list.

Comment: Not really clear question, please be specific and focus on ONE thing you want to know ;-) see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

> Do you first put the customers1...3 in a collection (three in all) or a list?

yes. And then call `randomFrom` to choose your customers group, then call it again to get a random customer from that group.

Comment: This doesnt really work with this example. If you put all three populations in a collection (by selecting and right clicking "Create Collection"), it creates a collection where the element class is Customer (not the population), I dont know  what the element class is for a population of agents. Then executing the randomFrom function on the collection, expectedly generates a set of Type Mismatches.

Comment: Well, even better, no? You get a random customer across all populations. Mathematically, it is the same as choosing a pop first and then a customer...

Comment: I understand that it would be the same. But I havent figured out how to properly group the three populations into a collection. It generate Type mismatches and cant be executed. Its because the collection needs and Element class, which cant be "Customer", as the elements arent customers but collections (or populations of customers).  Using Object for the populations solves the Type mismatch, but then the collection "cannot be resolved to a variable".  How do you group a set of Agent Populations into a collection?  Or What is the Element Class of a Population of Agents?

Comment: Don't go there, it is bad practice! Create an ArrayList collection of Customers. In the Customer agent-type properties "on startup", add each created customer to your collection on Main (or wherever it is). This way, all customers, independent of their population, will be part  of the collection.

Comment: 1 of 2: This doesnt work for what I want. Creating an ArrayList for all customers as they are created doesnt do anything for the customer populations. I have three customer populations that are created at the start. More customers are created during runtime. The ArrayList will add all the customers to it, but it wont help add the new ones randomly to customer sets 1,2 or 3. It will just add those to the ArrayList, that still wont be associated with customer groups.

Comment: 2 of 2: There is no place to add an action on a population properties. I cannot add the 3 populations to an ArrayList as populations. So the randomFrom function cannot work on populations. I think this is a flaw in Anylogic that it allows you to create a collection of populations but its of the wrong type. I am giving up.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a separate Agent Type for your Customer Populations, each with its own collection (e.g. ArrayList) of Customer Agents, then add your Customers to those collections. You will then be able to use the method of your choice to randomly select a Customer Population, along with all of its Customers (or references thereunto).  You can then also write functions etc. for your Customer Population Agent Type, which you may find useful.

In the Market Dynamics Model for which I'm responsible - and which Benjamin's team originally created - this is precisely how the global Population of Customer Agents are assigned to Banks (now Products), and I've had no reason so far (four years) to change it. You can easily move the Customer Agents between populations if you need to. Again, in my specific example, I've seen no need to alter the code I inherited, so this is facilitated by simply calling add/remove on the relevant ArrayLists of Customers.